# Why am I only able to get 18 exposures on a 24-exposure roll?

Tags: film

My daughter is taking a photography class in high school that requires a film camera.  She did not have one, so had to borrow.  She has only been able to get 18 exposures with it on a roll that is 24.  Her teacher loaded it, so I don't think that is the problem.... Any thoughts?

Comment: When you look at the negatives, are there large gaps between each frame? There should only be about 3mm between successive frames and the numbers on the edge of the film should line up in the same spot for each successive frame.

Comment: My daughter says she never looked at how the numbers line up but there are large gaps.

Comment: The teacher may have burned a few frames to demonstrate the camera's operation, possibly to show her how to tell if the film is advancing or some other function. What's on the first few exposed frames?

Comment: Has this happened just the once or on multiple rolls? What model camera is it? Are the gaps uniformly large or do they change?

Comment: My daughter says she never looked at how the numbers line up but there are large gaps between frames and they are not uniform sizes.  It has happened on multiple rolls....She says the camera is a Nikon N60.

Comment: I don't have experience with the N60 but from what I can tell, it's a film autofocus slr not unlike many, and includes a motor drive that should be automatically advancing the film. 
If the gap between frames is variable, this leads me to believe that something is going on with the film advance. Low batteries maybe? Damage?

Comment: I've heard of some old cameras with some kind of panorama format. Does the camera take 24*36mm images or some wider format? Maybe adding the camera type could be useful.

Comment: The OP would likely know if she had a pano camera, as they are much bigger and more expensive than regular 35mm cameras. Anyway,  Nikon N60 is not a pano camera.

Answer (score 2):

If the gaps between frames are unseemly large and not uniform - as I get from the comments section - you are likely to have a problem with the film advance. Film cameras are by definition old and by now likely to develop issues that require some CLA (Clean, Lube, Adjust).

Over time a layer of sticky goo accumulates in bearings, causing the film advance to turn unevenly. This is a common problem and easily solved, though best left to a skilled repairman. Luckily there are still trained servicemen around.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is actually happening, it seems necessary to expend the cost of the cheapest roll of film you can buy.  Load the film, but do NOT close the back of camera.  Leave it open so you can observe. This light exposure naturally ruins the film, but it's just one cheap roll.

On the loaded film, use ink to mark the left and right edge of the frame opening that it covers. Then click the shutter so you can advance the film by one position. The trailing edge mark should advance to very slightly beyond the leading frame edge.  Mark both frame edges again, and keep going, keep repeating until something is obvious. The end of roll might perform differently than the start of the roll.

At the end, you can unroll the film and check all the markings, and count the frames, etc.  Something should be much more obvious to you then. There should be only a very minimal spacing between frames.

The alternative option is to close the camera normally, then take all (24?) of the pictures regularly. Develop the film, but leave the film strip uncut, so you can see the positioning of all the frames.

Answer (score 1):

The 35mm cassette has ample film inside to deliver 24 exposures. Protruding from the cassette is a strip of exposed film called a tongue. The cassette drops into a supply side recess and the tongue is pulled exposing another few inches of film.  This now extended strip of film is drawn across an opening called a film gate. Then the tongue, which is light struck, is thus ruined. Now the camera is “fired” by actuating the shutter and the film is advanced. This action clears the exposed film bringing into play unexposed film. If the loader is too zealous, several beginning frames are lost. This can cut the expected 24 frame roll to a lower number.

Comment: It seems there are non-uniform gaps between pictures.  Problem advancing?

Comment: Gap should be about 2mm. Check the edge printing, See how the exposed frames align with the frame numbers. Frame numbers are repeated twice such a 2A 2B this pattern allows for 1/2 frame cameras. A full frame spans both. Note: Numbers and frames will not perfectly align, they only are approximate.

Comment: I will pass that along and, hopefully, she can check at school tomorrow.

Comment: @KathyP, if she can grab a shot of the exposed film with a smartphone and pass it to you to edit into the question, that would be useful.

Comment: There is no need to measure gaps or check frame number alignment to verify if a 135 film is transported correctly. Each exposure should be exactly 8 performation holes wide.

Comment: @ jambuo -- The frame size is fixed by the dimension's of the film gate. However the advance distance is a variable. Frames can overlap or be too widely spaced.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your interest and help!  I have asked her to get a picture of the exposed film to post here.  She has not gotten that to me yet.  In the meantime, Mr. Marcus, could you explain what you mean when you say the advance distance is variable.  Do you mean there is an adjustment that could change it?  I believe she said there is an automatic "stop" when you advance the film.

Comment: @ Kelly P -- No adjustments -- The advance mechanism on most 35mm film cameras does not work with precision. The spacing between frames will vary depending on the force applied and the friction induced by the roll length and film stiffness. However, this does not account for the 18 frames vs. 24 frames. I think this is a loading error or the film was re-wound prematurely. Don't let this one incident spoil the fun. When eating a watermelon, spit those seeds out and just keep on enjoying,

Comment: To give another light hearted comment: I have a camera that used to be able to cram 40 frames on a 36 roll. Not a winner though, as the frames overlapped (and thus were useless). A clear case of faulty film advance, easily repaired and now works like a charm.

Comment: Tryin to add a picture of the negatives.  Not working....I will say the spaces are not all at the beginning.